# Update table with from sub select

Tags: postgresql

I have two table a and b.
I want to update the row in table a that is the most recent insert for each id from the earliest insert in table b where a.id = b.id

I've been trying to use an update statement with a sub select in the from. 
If I execute the sub query on its own it returns x number of rows, however when I execute the whole update statement it updated y number of rows.

```
update a
set  title = b.title
    created_at = b.created_at
from
(
    select 
    e.id,e.title,e.created_at
    from
    (
        select
        l.id,
        l.title,
        l.created_at
        l.t_insert
        from b l
        left join b r
        l.id = r.id and l.t_insert > r.t_insert
    ) e
    join
    (
        select
        l.id,
        l.title,
        l.created_at,
        l.t_insert
       from a l
       left join a r on l.report_id = r.report_id and l.t_insert < 
       r.t_insert
    ) f
)
where
a.id=b.id
```

I want the same number of rows to be updated as returned in the sub select query in the from.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, having fewer rows updated than returned by the subquery could be because one row id is returned more than once in the subquery. If that happens, the update statement will still only update the row once. I'm assuming the statement you've provided is not exactly what you're running, but you should check that the subquery is not providing duplicates in the id field of the subquery (either using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` or by double checking your `JOIN` conditions.